# Giving properties to classes through the use of Interface

Tags: c#, interface

If you had classes like Page, News, etc. that describe content items and you wanted to implement the ability to add attachments (files or other types of items) to these classes would you create, for instance, an

```
public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
```

in each of these files or would you refactor this out into an Interface called IAttachmentContainer that only has this property

```
List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
```

and then use this interface with all these classes (make classes implement the interface)?

As you noticed, since we used a generic collection (List) our interface did not need any additional methods or did it and I missed them?

I could end up with a lot of these collections (besides Attachments there might also be Widgets, etc.) and I want to keep the solution as clean as possible. So far this interface way is the best one found the only thing bothering me is that those interfaces are mostly *methodless*.

Essentially I would end up with

```
public class News : IAttachmentContainer, IWidgetContainer, ...
```

Does this seem ok?

Comment: Are there going to be properties/methods similar to different Attachments/Widgets? If so you could define an interface `IContainer<T> where T : BaseContainedClass`. You'd still end up with something pretty simiar though.

Comment: Similar or should I say, the same, properties/methods will be used when working with Attachments across all content items (News, Pages,..) but the interfaces themselves will not be very similar. For instance, Attachments will basically end up being files and those will behave completely different from Widgets (Widgets being more of an UI items). But when a News and Page both implement IAttachmentContainer I want them both to deal with Attachments in the same way - with that I mean the same DB persistance behaviour, business rules, serialization handling etc.

Comment: It shouldn't really bother you that an interface has only properties and no methods.  A property getter is not very conceptually different from a method that takes no parameters.  As for your question, it's hard to say anything about how the design should be without more information regarding what kinds of manipulations you need to perform on attachments and widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems OK if you are going to use a functions like...

```
ProcessAttachments(IAttachmentContainer MyObject)...
```

Then you could pass it any object that implemented the attachment interface...

```
ProcessAttachments(NewsObject);
```

Comment: Yes, this is where I am going with my thinking and implementation.